# Should a crippled jew leave his non-jewish providing wife?

Tags: intermarriage, baal-teshuva

Should a crippled jew unable to provide for himself leave his non-jewish wife and rely on charity, even when knowing he won't get any charity and he'll land on the street under the cardboard, even when he's so highly crippled, for instance he lost both kidneys and needs haemodialysis thrice a week, and by leaving his working wife and her health insurance he'll be putting himself in a health or even life threatening situation?

Should a crippled jew in need of therapy to become healthy and fully able to provide for himself not leave his therapy guaranteeing non-jewish wife until he's healthy and only then leave her? Should he in such case inform his wife of the decision of leaving her once he'll be healthy again or should he wait for the day of health to come?

Comment: Caenu, this is quite a specific scenario. If it is one you encounter in real life, I encourage you to [consult a rabbi](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) and other relevant professionals for personal advice.

Comment: Jewishly he is not considered married. so in this case it seems the violations ( he should avoid are only) 1. having relations with a non jewish woman,  and 2. being in privet with her.: in my humble understanding a jew can have relations with a non jewish woman if it is necessary not to die. a jew is forbidden to cheat a non jew (also he can do it if it is to save his life) so it not life threatening he should tell her. it is forbidden not to live of charity if it is needed to stay alive. that was all in theory, in practice apply for Medicaid

Comment: (a lot of Jews pay taxes and they would be happy if their money when to heal a jew, especially if it will avoid him from having relations with a non jewish woman)

Answer (score 2):

This is such a complicated issue, both emotionally and fiscally.

Marrying a non-Jew is forbidden (Chinuch, 427:1). However, relations with a Nidah is worse, as it carries the weight of Kareis.

Nowhere does your query mention the emotional aspect of this relationship. Is the only reason that this disabled person remains in the relationship because of the support? Not only would this be morally dishonest to the partner, it is also un unnecessary. There are plenty of institutions and projects that can help with medical expenses and referrals.

Best of luck.